# jenkins Role-Based Strategy - project role patterns

Tags: authentication, jenkins, role-based

I am trying to provide a Role-Based Strategy project role patterns:

```
  Role to Add: sysadmin
  Pattern: *-stack
```

While saving those changes, I am getting following error in Jenkins

```
Stack trace
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*-stack
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.Role.<init>(Role.java:90)
    at com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy$DescriptorImpl.ReadRoles(RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.java:763)
    at com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.java:711)
    at com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy$DescriptorImpl.doRolesSubmit(RoleBasedAuthorizationStra
```

What is the error in my pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use shell regular expression to match the Jenkins projects.In this case we can use

```
Patter: \S*-stack
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using regex (.*) in place of *

```
(.*)-stack
```

Comment: Well I tried the accepted answer on my Jenkins installation, didn't work for me. Tried with the regex and it worked fine.

Comment: If anyone's looking: `(.*)` works as match all, while `.*` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to provide access to jobs inside the folder as well as to job in root:

```
folder_name.*|job_in_root
```

More information on this can be found here:

- https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036425292-Role-Based-Authorization-Strategy-Limit-folder-access